# Does Flex dispatch an event on a call to invalidateSkinState() in a SkinnableComponent?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I'm working with `SkinnableComponent`s on a Flex application, and I'm testing some component's behavior.

I'd like to test that a call to `invalidateSkinState()` is performed within a component on a custom event.
I tried to listen to different events like `FlexEvent.STATE_CHANGE_COMPLETE` but did not handle anything. The documentation does not say anything about this or I couldn't find where...

In other words, I'd like to know how a skin is told its state has changed by the hosted component.

Does anyone try to perform such tests and has found a solution?

I'll accept any solution even if it does not involve events, but I'd like to keep the tested code as it is now (i.e. no method overrides, no third event dispatches, etc.)

Comment: The invalidate methods don't fire events.  All the invalidate method does is queue up the component for changing state.  It does so by changing a Boolean value from false to true; and then adding the component on the layoutManager queue so it will be processed during the next render event.  You may want to listen for updateComplete if you want to know when the skin state change has been completed.IF you're only concerned w/ one component; you can override invalidateSkinState() to dispatch an event.

Comment: I tried to listen for `updateComplete` events without any more success. As I stated in my question I don't want to change the tested code. Anyway I fixed my problem by overriding `invalidateSkinState()` in my test case. And your comment helped me think my problem differently so thanks!

Comment: The problem with listening to events is that my test is making assertions right after my custom event is dispatched (so it is handled by my component). As it is unit testing, I can't wait for the `updateComplete` event to be dispatched.

Comment: My personal feeling is that unit tests are not good for testing UI Code.  Test suites which run the app as a user, such as those with QTP and/or FlexMonkey or RIATest are much better suited.  A lot of folks disagree w/ me on that one, of course. :-) In the case of unit testing; you may have been able to access the mx_internal flags.  But, nevertheless I'm glad you found a solution.  You should post it as a formal answer to your own question.

Comment: I must disagree too then ;). To me, frameworks like QTP or FlexMonkey cover different needs than unit tests even if I don't have any experience using them. Functional testing and integration testing might be better to test UI, but in this case, I don't really test the UI itself but a behavior. Differences are sometimes hard to tell though. Anyway I posted my solution as you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments by www.Flextras.com, a call to invalidateSkinState() doesn't fire any event.

Some events might be dispatched later on by the component when processed by the layout manager.
However, my problem is to test (unit test) that a call to `invalidateSkiState()` is performed by the tested component on a specific event, and I can't wait for such an event. Furthermore, the component is never added to the stage and so it will never be processed by the layout manager.

So I came up with a solution with involve extending the tested component class for test purposes. This way I don't have to modify the tested code.

Here is a sample of my test case class:

```
package com.example.components
{
    import org.flexunit.Assert;

    public class ComponentTests
    {
        [Test]
        public function testSkinStateIsInvalidatedOnCustomEvent():void
        {
            var component:ComponentForTests = new ComponentForTests();
            var event:CustomEvent = new CustomEvent();
            // Here we set up the event for the test

            testedComponent.init();
            testedComponent.isStateInvalidated = false;
            testedComponent.handleCustomEvent(event);
            Assert.assertTrue("Skin state should be invalidated",
                              testedComponent.isStateInvalidated);
        }
    }
}

import com.example.components.TestedComponent;

internal class ComponentForTests extends TestedComponent
{
    internal var isStateInvalidated:Boolean = false;

    override public function invalidateSkinState():void
    {
        isStateInvalidated = true;
        super.invalidateSkinState();
    }
}
```

I posted it here in case it can help someone else. Still, this solution is left open to criticism and any better solution is welcome.